# I've seen a few examples but I just can't figure it out in my case, If the query returns null, how can I have my expression in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

[image]My expressions returns the  values from field count from the dataset AC_HistoryTable10. i have only one table with one row to display the value in percentage.

Number 1 try

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Count.Value), 0 , (Fields!Count.Value))
```

the above still returns the text box as blank

Number 2 try

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Count.Value) OR Fields!Count.Value= "","0" , Fields!Count.Value)
```

the above still returns the text box as blank

Comment: You cannot have single quotes in an expression. Those are considered a comment indicator. Only use double quotes to see if a value is empty.

Comment: i did the changes but still the table shows the empty, instead of 0. is i am missing any thing

Comment: Your first expression really should work. I just tested it myself. Are you sure that you are getting back NULL? Or, is it an empty dataset (no rows)?

Comment: i am just calculating the percentage of PASS and FAIL, if PASS percentage is 100% then it will not show the FAIL Percentage so the dataset is empty(no rows)

Comment: If you want to check if the data set is empty, use the CountRows functions. Something like this: `=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") = 0, 0, Fields!Count.Value)`

Comment: No luck, still it shows the box as empty, Added the screen shot for reference, please let me know if any more details required

Comment: You l;ast expression is looking for an single space rather than an amtpy string. Remove the space between the quotes `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Count.Value) OR Fields!Count.Value= "","0" , Fields!Count.Value)`

Comment: Tried the same but no luck..!